# PhotoMos relay -calculating the right resistance value and input voltage

Tags: led, design, solid-state-relay

For a EM coil relay I would choose the input voltage based on the coil rating. And a freewheeling diode based on maximum reverse voltage that appears across the coil.

I am not able to find something that tells how to make sense of ratings provided in the PhotoMos datasheet. Below are the Specifications of a PhotoMos relay (link to datasheet. not able to attach snaps).

1.How to arrive at the input voltage across the LED (maybe a range)?
2.How to calculate the value of the external current limiting resistor? 
3.some articles speak about the RF rating of the external resistor used, how does this impact operation of the relay?

datasheet link:
http://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e_download/control/relay/photomos/catalog/semi_eng_rf1a_aqy22_s_cr10.pdf

Comment: On 3:  Which articles are you talking about?  Can you post  links or the salient part(s) of the articles?

Comment: It's a white paper by Panasonic titled "Working With Optically-Isolated Relays". Apparently they meant R-forward. It has nothing to do with RF(Radio frequency), It confused me because of being denoted as "RF value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are driving an LED and the rated forward current required is 50 mA maximum or 3 mA to guarantee operation at 25 C. Forward voltage is 1.14 V at 5 mA so I'd operate at 5 mA and you'll need to add a dropper resistor to prevent overload.

Typically from a 5V drive you'll need to "lose" 3.86 V across the resistor at 5 mA. This means the resistor value is 772 ohms so make it 750.

Comment: So I can drive it at a higher voltage if I choose a larger resistance in series? say at 12v

Comment: 12V-1.14V = 10.86V. 10.86V/5mA = 2172 ohms. I made a number error in my answer above that I'm correcting.

Comment: yup noticed, its around 700ohms

Comment: I'm still puzzled about the 3rd point. I'll wait a while, if no better answers show up, ill accept. Thanks for the prompt solution.

Comment: Can you link to an article that talks about point 3?

Answer (score 0):

\$ \text {1.} \$ The freewheeling diode should be chosen so that its maximum rated reverse voltage exceeds that of the relay supply, and its power dissipation chosen to be greater than the product of the diode's forward voltage and the relay coil's decaying "discharge" current integrated over the period of the discharge event and the number of events over time.

\$ \text {2.} \$  From Panasonic's data sheet:

[image]

You can see that the maximum forward current for the LED is 50mA, but it's guaranteed to switch at 3 mA.

However, they say that the "dropout voltage" whatever that is, is around 1.25 volts at 5mA. That's pretty close to the forward voltage for most any IRLED, so since you can't hurt the LED until you start getting up past 50 mA, I'd assume a forward voltage of 1.2 volts with 10 mA through the diode would be a good jumping-off place.

For any LED, the ballast resistor comes out to be:

$$Rs = \frac {Vs-Vf}{Iled} $$

Just to be sure, you should check the current with minimum and maximum supply voltage (Vs) and minimum and maximum LED Vf.

The LEDs for everybody's small MOS relays are pretty much the same, so you can get the Vf spread with If from just about any MOS relay data sheet, with Panasonic a notable exception.

Or, measure it.

Comment: Dropout voltage is the voltage drop that "appears" across the LED due to the forward resistance, when a particular value of current passes through it. So maybe it would increase on increasing the current from 5 ma to 10ma. Am I correct?

Comment: Thanks for that. :) You're right, but the change in voltage will be miniscule and that' s what the current limiting ballast resistor is in there for. The LED is a diode, albeit a sloppy-ish one, so once  the forward voltage (Vf)  has been increased past the dropout point, a small change in Vf will effect a large change in forward current.  Google "LED voltage curves" and peruse the images for a better understanding of the phenomenon.